# (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes - string with '\u'

Tags: python, unicode, future-proof

Writing my code for Python 2.6, but with Python 3 in mind, I thought it was a good idea to put

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

at the top of some modules. In other words, I am asking for troubles (to avoid them in the future), but I might be missing some important knowledge here. I want to be able to pass a string representing a filepath and instantiate an object as simple as

`MyObject('H:\unittests')`

In **Python 2.6**, this works just fine, no need to use double backslashes or a raw string, even for a directory starting with `'\u..'`, which is exactly what I want. In the `__init__` method I make sure all single `\` occurences are interpreted as '`\\`', including those before special characters as in `\a`, `\b`, `\f`,`\n`, `\r`, `\t` and `\v` (only `\x` remains a problem). Also decoding the given string into unicode using (local) encoding works as expected.

Preparing for **Python 3.x**, simulating my actual problem in an editor (starting with a clean console in Python 2.6), the following happens:

```
>>> '\u'
'\\u'
>>> r'\u'
'\\u'
```

(OK until here: `'\u'` is encoded by the console using the local encoding)

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> '\u'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
```

In other words, the (unicode) string is not interpreted as unicode at all, nor does it get decoded automatically with the local encoding. Even so for a raw string:

```
>>> r'\u'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'rawunicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX
```

same for  `u'\u'`:

```
>>> u'\u'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
```

Also, I would expect `isinstance(str(''), unicode)` to return `True` (which it does not), because importing unicode_literals should make all string-types unicode. **(edit:)** Because [in Python 3, all strings are sequences of Unicode characters](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html#divingin), I would expect `str(''))` to return such a unicode-string, and `type(str(''))` to be both  `<type 'unicode'>`, and  `<type 'str'>` (because all strings are unicode) but also realise that `<type 'unicode'> is not <type 'str'>`. Confusion all around...

**Questions**

- how can I best pass strings containing '`\u`'? (without writing '`\\u`')
- does `from __future__ import unicode_literals` really implement all Python 3. related unicode changes so that I get a complete Python 3 string environment?

edit:
In Python 3, **[`<type 'str'>` is a Unicode object](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)** and `<type 'unicode'>` simply does not exist. In my case I want to write code for Python 2(.6) that will work in Python 3. But when I `import unicode_literals`, I cannot check if a string is of `<type 'unicode'>` because:

- I assume `unicode` is not part of the namespace
- if `unicode` is part of the namespace, a literal of `<type 'str'>` is still unicode when it is created in the same module
- `type(mystring)` will always return `<type 'str'>` for unicode literals in Python 3

My modules use to be encoded in 'utf-8' by a `# coding: UTF-8` comment at the top, while my `locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]` returns 'cp1252'. So if I call `MyObject('çça')` from my console, it is encoded as 'cp1252' in Python 2, and in 'utf-8' when calling `MyObject('çça')` from the module. In Python 3, it will not be encoded, but a unicode literal.

edit:

I gave up hope about being allowed to avoid using '\' before a `u` (or `x` for that matter). Also I understand the limitations of importing `unicode_literals`. However, the many possible combinations of passing a string from a module to the console and vica versa with each different encoding, and on top of that importing `unicode_literals` or not and Python 2 vs Python 3, made me want to create an overview by actual testing. Hence the table below. [image]

In other words, `type(str(''))` does not return `<type 'str'>` in Python 3, but `<class 'str'>`, and all of Python 2 problems seem to be avoided.

Comment: found this helpful [blog](http://blog.ludovf.net/python-str-unicode/): Strings and unicode in Python (2vs3) by Ludovico Fischer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK, all that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` does is to make all **string literals** of unicode type, instead of string type. That is:

```
>>> type('')
<type 'str'>
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> type('')
<type 'unicode'>
```

But `str` and `unicode` are still different types, and they behave just like before.

```
>>> type(str(''))
<type 'str'>
```

Always, is of `str` type.

About your `r'\u'` issue, it is by design, as it is equivalent to ru'\u' without `unicode_literals`. From the docs:

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is used in conjunction with a 'u' or 'U' prefix, then the \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences are processed while all other backslashes are left in the string.

Probably from the way the lexical analyzer worked in the python2 series. In python3 it works as you (and I) would expect.

You can type the backslash twice, and then the `\u` will not be interpreted, but you'll get two backslashes!

> Backslashes can be escaped with a preceding backslash; however, both remain in the string

```
>>> ur'\\u'
u'\\\\u'
```

So IMHO, you have two simple options:

- Do not use raw strings, and escape your backslashes (compatible with python3):

  `'H:\\unittests'`
- Be too smart and take advantage of unicode codepoints (**not** compatible with python3):

  `r'H:\u005cunittests'`

Comment: [In Python 3, all strings are sequences of Unicode characters](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html#divingin). Thus, if `type(str(''))` returns `<type 'str'>`, but a str object is a unicode, and should also be equal to `<type 'unicode'>`, which of course, cannot be both true. So I'm confused...

Comment: In puthon 3 all strings are sequences of Unicode characters, so there is only one type of strings, named `str`. In python 2 you have two types of strings: single-byte strings are `str`, and unicode strings are `unicode`. Putting it simple, Python2 `unicode` equals Python3 `str`, and Python2 `str` does not exist anymore in Python3 (or `bytes` if you like, but that's not actually a string).

Comment: So in Python 3, `type(str(''))` returns `<type 'str'>` (meaning unicode), and in Python 2, by importing `unicode_literals`, the new string-type (unicode) is introduced but  `<type 'str'>`  still means  `<type 'str'>`  as in the Python 2 context? Meaning that the use of `importing unicode_literals` is quite limited for testing for future-proving of your code and you can still run into much unicode trouble when you migrate...?

Comment: Exactly. That's why it is called `unicode_literals`  and not `unicode_strings`. Only the literals change meaning; this is necessary to avoid breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Meh, a poor decision in Python 2 to declare `r` to mean a raw string with backslashes not treated specially, **except before a `u`.** Glad this was fixed in Python 3, but still… ugh.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue related to version not up to date, in this case `numpy`

To fix :

```
conda install -f numpy
```

Answer (score -1):

I try this on Python 3:

> import os
>
> os.path.abspath("yourPath")

and it's worked!

Answer (score -2):

When you're writing string literals which contain backslashes, such as paths (on Windows) or regexes, use raw strings. That's what they're for.

Comment: Not in this setting. After `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, you can't use raw strings for strings that contain `\u` any more.